# Populating dropdown with LINQ query that has a calculated column

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm using a function to return a number of years calculated from a datetime column, and am having trouble figuring out how to reference the calculated column when trying to populate a dropdown.

Here is my Linq query:

```
 var q = (from a in db.Applications
          where a.uID == ID
          select a.date.Year).Distinct();
 return q.ToList();
```

So, when I go to populate the dropdown...

```
Dropdown1.DataTextField = ?????
```

Comment: You can use an anonymous type as `select new {Year=a.date.Year}`

Comment: Try setting `Dropdown1.DataTextField` to `"Year"`. It seems to use reflection to get the value of the property whose name you specify: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx

Comment: I tried to use "Year" but I got an error that "Year" wasn't found.

Comment: @MetalAdam: Yes, you need to create the anonymous type first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a list of value types is used as the DataSource, the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties do not need to be set.

See below:

```
private List<int> GetYears()
{
    var q = (from a in db.Applications
             where a.uID == ID
             select a.date.Year).Distinct();

    return q.ToList();
}
```

The dropdown would then be initialized like this:

```
Dropdown1.DataSource = GetYears();
// Dropdown1.DataTextField = null;  // Does not need to be set
// Dropdown1.DataValueField = null; // Does not need to be set
```

Comment: Not needing to set the DataValueField/DataTextField was where I was going wrong. Thanks, Mun!

Comment: @MetalAdam No probs, good to hear that worked. I've edited the answer to better reflect this.